# How do I correctly implement an interface with a method that has Object as an argument?

Tags: java, object, interface

I'm writing a program our professor has given us as homework.

I have a class called `Car`, that has two private real members `x` and `y`, which are supposed to represent the coordinates of the car in the coordinate plane, and I wanted to implement an interface called `MyInterface`, in which I declared a method `public boolean compare(Object t)`. It was stated it has to be `Object t` and not something else, so that I can implement the interface in multiple classes (part of the homework). Java is the programming language in question.

The part of the code that that is problematic looks like this:

```
public interface MyInterface {
      public boolean compare(Object t);
}


public class Car implements MyInterface{

      private double x, y;

      @Override
      public boolean compare(Car t) {
          double curdist = Math.sqrt(this.x*this.x + this.y*this.y);
          double givdist = Math.sqrt(t.x*t.x + t.y*t.y);
          if(curdist < givdist) return true;
          else return false;
    }

}
```

My method `compare` needs to calculate the distances from the point (0,0) for the current car and the given car, and compare the two distances. If the current car's distance (`curdist`) is closer from the given car's distance (`givdist`) to (0,0), `compare` returns true, otherwise it returns false.

My question is, how do I correctly implement this method in the class Car?
I've tried a few things, but none of them seem to work out. Any help is appreciated, 'cause I am quite new to object-oriented programming. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your interface method param is of type Object and your param for compare method in Car class is of type Car. Why? :)

Comment: @amseager I don't think it is gonna compile.

Comment: The professor wrote in our homework paper that our interface needs to have Object as the method parameter, because we need to implement the same interface in three different classes (which are essentially three different exercises). Last class he taught us interfaces, casting, and whatnot, so I guess this is his way of seeing what we've learned B)

Comment: @amseager Covariant _return_ types exist in Java, but not covariant parameter types.

Comment: Use 'instanceof' and casting to accomplish this.

Comment: Ohh, yeah. I really need to go to sleep :) sorry

Comment: @amseager I'm sure it won't compile, but I haven't even tried to, cause I have not figured out the error it gives. I have written the setters and getters, that's not the problem, I was just wondering how I can implement the method compare in my class Car if in the interface the method parameter is an Object

Comment: @aglassman I've tried casting, but I can't seem to figure where exactly to cast.

Comment: I think your implementation is wrong.  You can't specify `Car t`, it must be `Object t`, then you would do `Car car = (Car)t;`

Comment: That's another way to solve it @aglassman. Thank you for your suggestion, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must have `Object` as the parameter type for `compare`, then you must test the class of the parameter passed in to make sure it's a `Car` first.

Change the `compare` argument to `Object` in your `Car` class.  Then the `@Override` annotation will determine that the method is properly overriding the instance method, and you won't get a compiler error.  Use the `instanceof` operator to determine if `t` is a `Car`.  You may decide to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if it isn't a `Car`, or if it's `null`.  Then you can cast it to a `Car` and continue with the logic of your method.

Even if you have to do have it take `Object` for your class, a better way to do this in general is with generics.  Here, this would answer the question "What is this class comparable *to*?".  If you've covered generics, then you may understand a class that is defined as `MyInterface<T>`.  The `compare` method would take a parameter of type `T`.  This allows you to implement the method in `Car` with a parameter of type `Car`, provided `Car implements MyInterface<Car>`.  This is similar to the existing `Comparable` interface built-in to Java.

Comment: I don't think we've covered generics, but the first part of your answer will about solve what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your time!